# VBA How To Skip a line in with StreamReader

Tags: vba, excel, streamreader

In VBA, I have to compare the two versions of a text file and print the lines that do not match. However, if an additional (user-specified) line has been added to the more recent text file, this line must be ignored, and the comparison must continue with the next line in the more recent text file. The text files are quite large and I cannot use the ReadAll property.
Up until now I have assumed that there are the same number of lines in each text file and the order remains the same, therefore I used only the first text file to loop through all the lines.

```
Dim JsonPrev, JsonCurr As String  'Names of the text files
Dim strLinePrev , strLineCurr As String  'The file text
Dim UserLineAdded As String

LineAdded = MsgBox("Does the most recent JSON contain an additional input / output, which the first does not?", vbYesNo, "Alert!")

    If LineAdded <> vbNo Then
        UserLineAdded = InputBox("Please provide the line that was added" & vbNewLine & "E.g. INPUT AdjustToDate, or OUTPUT Surrender Charge Base")
        If UserLineAdded = vbNullString Then
            MsgBox ("Comparison cancelled.")
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

JsonPrev = Range("JSONPrevious").Value  'First Text File name
JsonCurr = Range("JSONCurrent").Value   'Second Text File name

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFilePrev = objFSO.OpenTextFile(JsonPrev, 1)
Set objFileCurr = objFSO.OpenTextFile(JsonCurr, 1)

DiffCount = 0

Do Until objFilePrev.AtEndOfStream
    strLinePrev = objFilePrev.ReadLine
    StrLineCurr = objFileCurr.ReadLine

    prevLineNumber = prevLineNumber + 1
    currLineNumber = currLineNumber + 1
    If prevLineNumber > 0 Or currLineNumber > 0 Then
        'Check whether a Line was added
        If InStr(1, UCase(StrLineCurr), UCase(UserLineAdded)) Then
            currLineNumber = currLineNumber + 1
            '*****Add code to update StrLineCurr to the next ReadLine*****
        End If

        If strLinePrev <> StrLineCurr Then
                DiffCount = DiffCount + 1
                'code to print both lines from different sources
            End If
        End If
    End If

Loop

objFilePrev.Close
objFileCurr.Close
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you find (user-specified) line in the first file , I assume  you need to ignore also the corresponding line in the second file.

modify your code

```
Do Until objFilePrev.AtEndOfStream
  strLinePrev = objFilePrev.ReadLine
  StrLineCurr = objFileCurr.ReadLine

  prevLineNumber = prevLineNumber + 1
  currLineNumber = currLineNumber + 1
 '''''''''''''''''
 ' add the next line , and define the function user_specified

 if user_specified(strLinePrev) then Continue While   ' ignore it

....

 loop
  ....

  ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
function user_specified(line as string) As Boolean
 ' define the logic of user specified string
  ' return True ?false

end function
```